# hdfs : File does not exist

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I have tried to read the data from s3 bucket and do the computation in spark and write the output to s3 bucket. This process has been completed successfully.But, at EMR step level i see there was job failed. If i see the log it is showing that File does not exist.

Please see the log below.

```
19/01/09 08:40:37 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-30-0-84.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal/172.30.0.84:8032
19/01/09 08:40:37 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 2 NodeManagers
19/01/09 08:40:37 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (106496 MB per container)
19/01/09 08:40:37 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
19/01/09 08:40:37 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
19/01/09 08:40:37 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
19/01/09 08:40:37 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
19/01/09 08:40:39 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
19/01/09 08:40:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-e0c6fbd3-14b0-4fcd-bbd2-c78658fdefd0/__spark_libs__8470659354947187213.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-30-0-84.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1547023042733_0001/__spark_libs__8470659354947187213.zip
19/01/09 08:40:47 INFO Client: Uploading resource s3://dev-system/SparkApps/jar/rxsicheck.jar -> hdfs://ip-172-30-0-84.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1547023042733_0001/rxsicheck.jar
19/01/09 08:40:47 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://dev-system/SparkApps/jar/rxsicheck.jar' for reading
19/01/09 08:40:47 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-e0c6fbd3-14b0-4fcd-bbd2-c78658fdefd0/__spark_conf__4575598882972227909.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-30-0-84.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1547023042733_0001/__spark_conf__.zip
19/01/09 08:40:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
19/01/09 08:40:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
19/01/09 08:40:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/01/09 08:40:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/01/09 08:40:47 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/01/09 08:40:47 INFO Client: Submitting application application_1547023042733_0001 to ResourceManager
19/01/09 08:40:48 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1547023042733_0001
19/01/09 08:40:49 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:40:49 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1547023248110
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ip-172-30-0-84.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1547023042733_0001/
     user: hadoop
19/01/09 08:40:50 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:40:51 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:40:52 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:40:53 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:40:54 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:40:55 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:40:56 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:40:57 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:40:58 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:40:59 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:00 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:01 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:02 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:03 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:04 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:05 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:06 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:07 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:08 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:09 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:10 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:11 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:12 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:13 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:14 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:15 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:16 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:17 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/09 08:41:18 INFO Client: Application report for application_1547023042733_0001 (state: FAILED)
19/01/09 08:41:18 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1547023042733_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1547023042733_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://ip-172-30-0-84.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:8088/cluster/app/application_1547023042733_0001Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: File does not exist: hdfs://ip-172-30-0-84.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1547023042733_0001/__spark_libs__8470659354947187213.zip
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://ip-172-30-0-84.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1547023042733_0001/__spark_libs__8470659354947187213.zip
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1547023248110
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://ip-172-30-0-84.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:8088/cluster/app/application_1547023042733_0001
     user: hadoop
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1547023042733_0001 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1122)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1168)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
19/01/09 08:41:18 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/01/09 08:41:18 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-e0c6fbd3-14b0-4fcd-bbd2-c78658fdefd0
Command exiting with ret '1'
```

I can see the my expected output result but job shows it is failed.  Am i missing anything?

Here is the my code:

```
package Spark_package

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object SampleFile {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("SampleFile").getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SampleFile")
    val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

    val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load("s3a://test-system/Checktool/Zipdata/*.gz")

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
    val res = spark.sql("select count(*) from data")

    res.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header","true").mode("Overwrite").save("s3a://dev-system/Checktool/bkup/")

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

kindly help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Any help on this please?

Comment: Please help me on this issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the master(local[*]) and run it on respective cluster works.